# How can I call a method within mutation method using VueJS 2?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I got a problem here. I don't know how to call a method within mutation method, I've tried `this.show()` but it doesn't work, is there's a way like `actions` in vuex that you can call a method within the `action` using `dispatch` ?

```
// Mutation
export default {
    show(state, payload) {
       // execute code
    },
    hide(state, payload) {
       // how to call show method?
    }
}
```

I want mutation look like this

```
// Action
export default {
    show({ state }, payload) {
       // execute code
    },
    hide({ dispatch, state }, payload) {
      // how to call show method look like this in mutation?
      // Is this possible for mutation?
      return dispatch('show', payload)
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to commit a mutation in anotger mutation?

Comment: I want to hide something and I want it to place in mutation, is that possible? or it must be done in action?

Comment: That's only a presentation of what I want to do, sorry for the class name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VueJS 2 you should use **$emit** instead of **$broadcast** as described in documentation - https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#dispatch-and-broadcast-replaced

Comment: Thank you for your answer bro, this is noted.